# TypeError when running selenium web driver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, css-selectors

I'm currently in the middle of an online python course and have been mostly progressing without issue, or at the very least eventually being able to solve them, however this one has me stumped. I'm attempting to pull html data (the course is using the Python website for this example) and am getting a "TypeError" every time the process finishes, as far as I can tell I've written everything exactly the way the instructor did in the course video so I'm not sure if I'm just being stupid and missing something obvious or if it doesn't have anything to do with what I'm doing and is an actual glitch.

So far I've tried everything I have found online, from running the for loop through a "try" statement and so forth, to no avail. I'll post a copy of my code (and the corresponding error) below.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://www.python.org/")

event_times = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".event-     widget time")
event_names = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".event-    widget li a")
events = {}

for n in range(len(event_times)):
    events[n] = {
        "time": event_times[n].text,
        "name": event_names[n].text,
    }

print(events)

driver.quit()
```

[The response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5hwn.png)

Comment: Please post your code as text instead of an image.

Comment: With `event_times` being None means it could not be found on the page. Either the selector is configured wrong or you are crawling the wrong page.

Comment: you might try just checking if (event_times) {...it's not a zero size array ...}

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try changing `driver.find_elements_by_css` to `driver.find_elements(BY.CSS)`